# How to edit the newly added item from a row using angular8

Tags: angular, reactive

i am using reactive forms, if i edit the values which is already present in database it gets edited and gets saved in that particular row, as it has unique id as agentw9id, but if i create new item and edit that, it gets added with the new id, so i tried with this method, here, for index 0, it doesnt work but for other values it used to get update, but it used to go all values at time of final save instead of sending the edited change of the newly added items.

DEMO:
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-ck3u8u-rdrazg?file=src/app/user-table/user-table.component.ts)

TS:

```
saveW9Details(item) {
this.addButtonDisable = false;
        if(this.employee ) {
          if(item.agentW9id.value) {
            for(var i=0;i<this.employee.length;i++){
              if(this.employee[i].agentW9id===item.agentW9id.value){
                this.employee[i].taxId=item.taxId.value;
                this.employee[i].businessType=item.businessType.value;
                this.employee[i].signatureDate=item.signatureDate.value;
                this.employee[i].agentW9id = item.agentW9id.value;
                // updated=true;
                this.temporaryControls.push(this.employee[i]);
                this.getFormData.removeAt(i)
              }
           }
          } else {

            var temp={
              taxId:item.taxId.value,
              signatureDate:item.signatureDate.value,
              businessType: item.businessType.value,
              agentW9id:item.agentW9id.value,
             originalFileName:item.fileName.value?item.fileName.value.slice(12):''
            }
            if(this.employee) {
              this.employee.push(temp);
              this.temporaryControls.push(temp)
            } 
      //  this.getFormData.removeAt(item)
          }
        } else {
         console.log(item,"dsds")

            let temp={
              taxId:item.taxId.value,
              signatureDate:item.signatureDate.value,
              businessType: item.businessType.value,
              agentW9id:item.agentW9id.value,
              businessName: item.businessName[0].value,
             originalFileName:item.fileName.value?item.fileName.value.slice(12):''
            };
            this.temporaryControls.push(temp)
        }

       this.getFormData.removeAt(item);


        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looping on actual FormArray. This way you will get hold of each control. and then you can pass this control to edit function. This way you dont need to worry about index.

Comment: thanks for response, Can i have a sample or example for this? could uhelp me out to achieve this

Comment: any idea about my question how can this be handled??

Comment: any idea about this issue?