# How to remove the validation error after putting proper input values using angular8

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

i am using reactive forms where in i have put validation error for the phone number, if i had given less than 10 digit number then it must show the error message, when 10 numbers are there the validation message must be hided. But here all time this validation number remains same.

DEMO:
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-phone-mask-tjunur?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Phone Number <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="(###) ### - ####" formControlName="agentPhone"
                  name="phoneNumber" autocomplete="new-phone" (keypress)=_keyPress($event)
                  [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && detailsInfo.agentPhone.errors }" appPhoneMask maxlength="14">
                <div *ngIf="submitted && detailsInfo.agentPhone.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                  <div *ngIf="detailsInfo.agentPhone.errors.required">Phone number is required</div>
                  <div *ngIf="detailsInfo.agentPhone.errors.pattern">please enter valid Phone number</div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Ts:

```
  _keyPress(event: any) {
    const pattern = /[0-9]/;
    let inputChar = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);
    if (!pattern.test(inputChar)) {
        event.preventDefault();

    }
}

this.agentbasicInfoForm = this.FB.group({
        agentPhone: ['', [Validators.required,Validators.pattern('[1-9]\\d{9}')]],
})
```

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: Yes I will try to create and update

Comment: @Chellappanவ i had updated demo in question, please have a look.

Comment: It' seems your regex pattern is wrong, What is your requirement only numbers are allowed?

Comment: here my pattern should be (###) ### - ####, and here if the length of the phone number is less, then it must throw validation error, like if it is something like (###) - ##, then validation error must be thrown of enter valid phone number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you correctly:
use this regex:

```
Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{10}$')
```

or you can just specify it in the length validator

```
Validators.minLength(10)
Validators.pattern('^[0-9]*$')
```

EDIT:
I edited your code and now it works:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-phone-mask-unmfkc?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: thanks for response, but sorry it is not working, my requirement is like, i want the phone number to be masked like this (###) - ### - ####, and if the length is less than 10 numbers it must show validation error, but here all time validation error is coming even though 10 numbers has been inputted.

Comment: Ok im still trying to figure out what exactly you're trying to do
You want the user to type to include the symbols or you want the symbols to stay in the placeholder while the user types (which is not possible to my knowledge)?

if you want the user to type symbols (dashes, parentheses etc) you need to clean the final input

const phone = '123123dsadsa0';
const arr = phone.match(/\d+/g).concat().join('') // result '1231230'


or you can separate to 3 inputs and combine them in the TS
Then you can validate each input separately.

the validators check all the characters in the input.

Comment: are you able to run the demo which I had provided link?? In that link my issue is there, while user types the phone number, it is taking (dashes and parenthesis) but even though user has given 10 numbers excluding these dashes and parenthesis, the red colour validation message still remains same, my concern is that, when user types 10 digit number excluding dashes and parenthesis the validation message should get hidden but in my case it is still showing

Comment: Have you got time to go through my question?

Comment: any idea about this issue?

Comment: this what you meant?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-phone-mask-unmfkc?file=app/app.component.html

Comment: thanks for your answer and it is working as per my requirement.

Comment: any idea about this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59997796/how-to-edit-the-newly-added-item-from-a-row-using-angular8/59998184#59998184

Comment: I edit my answer please mark at as answered
I hope to look at the other issue soon

Comment: ya i have accepted and voted, any idea about the question i posted, if so please help me